# What is the idiomatic approach for logging long messages in a structured logging system like MEL and Serilog?

Tags: logging, serilog, structured-logging

My ASP.NET Core 2.x web-application makes idiomatic use of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` for doing "trace"-style logging when I want to store a short (<200 character) parameterised string. These kinds of logged events work well with the tooling and ecosystem built around structured logging systems like Serilog.

e.g.

```
public IActionResult DisplayCustomers(String customerName, String country)
{
    this.logger.LogInformation( "Search performed for customers named {name} in {country}.", customerName, country );
}
```

However, my application also has a need to log somewhat large text-blobs (2-3KB) that are built-up by the application using a `StringBuilder` as well as similar text-blobs generated by third-party components, typically these consume an `IProgress<String>` that output lots of short string values in a similar way to the ad-hoc use of `Console.WriteLine`.

e.g.

```
// Backend method (no structured logging available):
public void ProcessData(LotsOfData data, IProgress<String> report)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < data.Records.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( i % 500 == 0 ) report.Report( String.Format( "{0}ms - Processed {1} records.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, i ) );

        if( data.Records[i].Foo )
        {
            // (send job off to SQL Server and get back SPROC output via PRINT and RAISERROR)
            String sprocRaiseErrorOutput = ...
            report.Report( "Sproc output: " +  sprocRaiseErrorOutput );
        }

        if( data.Records[i].Bar ) report.Report( "Contents of bar: " +  data.Records[i].Bar.Text );
    }
    report.Report( "{0}ms - Completed.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds );
}

class StringBuilderProgress : IProgress<String>
{
    private StringBuilder sb;
    public StringBuilderProgress(StringBuilder sb) { this.sb = sb; }

    public void Report(String value) { this.sb.AppendLine( value ); }
}

// Frontend method:
public IActionResult ProcessData(LotsOfData data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilderProgress sbp = new StringBuilderProgress( sb );

    backendService.ProcessData( data, sbp );

    this.logger.LogInformation( "Process data ran: {report}", sb.ToString() );
}
```

...which results in a large, unstructured text blob that contains useful information and needs to viewed by itself in isolation, but which does not lend itself well to existing structured logging tooling.

I recognize a general solution is to write a wrapper for `ILogger` that implements `IProgress<String>` - but there are a few issues with this approach:

- Each output line in the original text-blob becomes a structured object, encumbered with its own additional properties which would significantly bloat the size of the log.
- It would result in duplicate data, e.g. the structured logging system would add timestamps, but the text already contains Stopwatch time values too.
- Often a text blob contains things like ACII-art for boxes and indicating processing regions and each line is indented to represent a deeper level of processing - this information would be lost if each line is stored individually and independently of its textual context.

  - And what use is a log entry that simply contains the first line of an ASCII art rectangle box?

Is there a way in Serilog or MEL to handle text blobs specially? Such as outputting them to their own file?

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily implement a sink to parse outputs ([sorry, don't have this in C#](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/7732ec2f12d58f45916450276acd36cdd6a76421/samples/Store/Integration/Infrastructure.fs#L31)) as you see fit and render appropriately, either to file of your own shape or onward to a log. Alternately you can sequester stuff as properties into the log entries and then process them in the sink and/or log chain in general using the filtering mechanisms afforded there ([deeper example](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/e4a28f62bc1a301a98f0cc791c8072bfa60c3829/samples/Store/Integration/LogIntegration.fs)].

- In a custom sink, you get access to a `Serilog.Events.LogEvent` which holds the structure in mostly immutable form, but admits the possibility to add/remove properties.

  Thus you should be able to extract embedded properties and write them onward to a separate log (and delete them from LogEvent before allowing it to proceed). If you do this inside an `Async` sink chain, it also wont impact perf of writers.
- another option is to render as json [using the variety of renditions possible](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact), and then postprocess yourself out of band
- Finally, if you tag stuff well and/or have relevant identifying marks correlating items, things like [Seq](http://getseq.net) are built for parsing things like this efficiently (though I'm not aware of a way of rendering something as Fixed Width format in there) (stuff also gets compressed in the stores etc and the full event is always retained)